# Javadoc error while generating

Tags: java, android, eclipse, error-handling, javadoc

Every time I attempt to generate Javadocs, it gives me an error:

> javadoc: error - invalid flag: -bootclasspath path/to/jar/android.jar

What am I suppose to do?

Comment: How do you generate the JavaDocs? Are you using Terminal, Eclipse or Android Studio/IntelliJ for that?

Comment: i'm using eclipse, project - generate javadoc